# Profiling a Linux kernel code snippet in Intel VTune

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, performancecounter, intel-vtune

I am trying to profile a specific code snippet in a device driver in the Linux kernel.
I want to know the hardware events that occur during the execution of this code block.
I wanted to know whether this task can be done using Intel VTune.

I saw that VTune provides the ITT API for starting and stopping data collections at a specific place in the code, but I could not find out whether this method is compatible with kernel functions.

I currently use manual instrumentation in the kernel code and read performance counters using wrmsr and rdmsr assembly instructions. But I can only read 4 counters (in Intel Xeon Ice Lake) at a time without using multiplexing.
I would like to read many uncore counters for my task.

Please let me know if someone has tried this or knows any alternative methods that can help with my task.

System details:
Intel Xeon Silver 4314
Linux kernel 5.15

Comment: AFAIK, VTune is meant to profile user-code,not kernel one. That being said, I expect VTune to correctly gather the hardware events generated in kernel-based code if the rights are configured correctly (in `perf` for example, you need to set `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` to `-1`). Can't you use `perf` instead? It is meant to profile both user and kernel space code. It is the main recommanded tool (and a standard one) for kernel profiling.

Comment: The limit of the number of counters is not a software one but one fixed by the hardware (i.e. CPU micro-architecture). If you want to bypass this limit, then multiplexing is mandatory. Both perf and VTune does that. An alternative solution is to run multiple time the profiling with different events (but results of different runs should not be compared to be rigorous).

Comment: The only method I saw using perf is to manually instrument the kernel code using perf_event_open and read multiple counters. I could not find a proper example (or documentation) on how to do this for more than 3-4 counters (I already can read 4 counters using assembly). Is there any other way to read multiple counters for a kernel code snippet using perf (ideally without instrumenting)?

Comment: I currently read 4 counters at a time for this task but I have around 90 counters that I would like to read initially (to figure out the root cause of a performance bottleneck). I am looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: AFAIK, `perf` should be able to do that by default if properly configured as previously mentioned. That being said reading 90 counters concurrently (using multiplexing) is not reasonable IMHO. It seems like a brute-force strategy and the result is generally complete garbage (unless the trace is huge which impact performance and so the quality of the results). In general, counters should be used to confirm/invalidate an hypothesis, not to find ones. The hypothesis should be built based on the code.

Comment: Another approach in profiling is to make a global analysis based on rather generic counters and then refine the profiling based on the gathered results. This means focusing on a class of events rather than others. For example, you find that the IMC throughput is bigger than expected, then focus on L2/L3 cache misses, and then L3 RFO, but not directly all counters, nor all memory-related counters (which is as crazy as instrumenting every kernel function IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Using Intel® VTune™ Profiler, can you try the instructions provided in the documentation for Linux Kernel Analysis: [Enabling Linux Kernel Analysis - Intel® VTune™ Profiler](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/vtune-profiler/user-guide/2024-0/enabling-linux-kernel-analysis.html)

To collect additional counters, you can try using a custom collector as documented in the link: [Custom Data Collection For Performance Analysis - Intel® VTune™ Profiler](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/vtune-profiler/cookbook/2023-2/custom-data-collection-for-performance-analysis.html)